# How to set height of ScrollView in Android?

Tags: android

I am very new in Android development I have designed the xml below

I started with creating a `ConstraintView` inside of that I created a `ConstraintView` with some fixed height and `ScrollView`.

I am facing problem to set the height of `Scrollview`. How to set `ScrollView` should start just below to `ConstraintView`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/CL1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:background="@color/color_primary_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is your end layout goal here, but you can simply set a top to bottom constraint on your `ScrollView` like you have done on your `RecyclerView`. So just add the following in your `ScrollView` XML

```xml
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/CL1"
```

So your XML becomes

```xml
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/CL1"
        android:background="@color/color_primary_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
```

Comment: Thanks can you please tell the difference between ```ScrollView``` and ```NestedScrollView```

Comment: `NestedScrollView` as the name suggests is used when there is a need for a scrolling view inside another scrolling view. Normally this would be difficult to accomplish since the system would be unable to decide which view to scroll.

Also please mark the answer as correct if it helped you.